# How does \uput determine the touching point between the object box and the hypothetical circle?

Tags: pstricks, teaching

> This question offers 4 bounties of 500 each only for a single answer that
>   fit this question best.

I am interested in describing the behavior of `\uput` for non-zero dimensional objects. Non-zero dimensional objects are objects with prepared containers at TeX level. Zero dimensional objects have zero containers at TeX level.

For zero dimensional objects, its behavior has been known as follows and now it is no longer interesting to me.

[image]

Lets consider the 2 cases below:

### Case 1:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone} 
\SpecialCoor
\usepackage{multido} 

\def\NonZeroDimenObject{%
    \pspicture(2,1)
        \psframe(2,1)
        \psline[linecolor=blue]{->}(1,.5)(2,.5)
    \endpspicture}

\SpecialCoor

\begin{document} 

\multido{\i=0+15}{24}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](8,8)
    \pscircle(4,4){2}
    \psline[origin={4,4}](3.5;\i)
    \rput(4,4){\i}
    \uput{2}[\i]{0}(4,4){\NonZeroDimenObject}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

### Case 2:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone} 
\SpecialCoor
\usepackage{multido} 

\def\NonZeroDimenObject{%
    \pspicture(2,1)
        \psframe(2,1)
        \psline[linecolor=blue]{->}(1,.5)(2,.5)
    \endpspicture}

\SpecialCoor

\begin{document} 

\multido{\i=0+15}{24}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](8,8)
    \pscircle(4,4){2}
    \rput(4,4){\i}
    \uput{2}[0]{\i}(4,4){\NonZeroDimenObject}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

### Questions:

I have 3 questions:

1. For the given `\alpha` (or the second argument), a line from `(i_x,i_y)` to `(i_x,i_y)+(r;\alpha)` does not always point to the touching point between the object box and the hypothetical circle of radius `labelsep`. How does `\uput` determine the touching point? Explaining the internal algorithm should be fine.
2. The pivot seems not to be static. How does `\uput` determine the touching point? Explaining the internal algorithm should be fine.
3. When do we really need `\uput`? Please give me at least 2 practical unique examples that cannot be replaced by other put macros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone} 
\SpecialCoor
\usepackage{multido} 

\def\Width{3 }
\def\Height{1 }
\def\NonZeroDimenObject#1{%
    \pspicture(\Width,\Height)\psframe(\Width,\Height)\endpspicture}    
\SpecialCoor
\psset{dotscale=0.5}
\begin{document} 

\multido{\i=0+5}{73}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](9,8)
    \multido{\iB=0+1}{\i}{\uput{2}[\iB]{0}(4,4){\pspicture(\Width,\Height)\psdot(!\Width 2 div \Height 2 div)\endpspicture}}
    \pscircle(4,4){2}
    \rput(4,4){\psline[linecolor=blue]{->}(3;\i)}
    \rput(4,4){\i}
    \uput{2}[\i]{0}(4,4){\NonZeroDimenObject{\i}}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

The first one with `labelsep=0`. If it is not a square it will be translatet with a transformation matrix.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I need the relationship between the angle `\alpha` (the second argument) and the coordinate of the touching point. :-)

Comment: How to draw the dashed rectangle on the right animation? I don't know how to get its coordinates.

Comment: For your example with a frame of 2,1 its `\psframe[linestyle=dashed](! 5.9 4 2 sqrt sub)(! 2 1 Pyth 6 add 4 2 sqrt add)` I forgot how I calculated the left value, the reason why I chose 5.9

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, the interpretation is obvious:

1. `\uput{2}[\i]{0}(4,4){\NonZeroDimenObject}`

   Consider the 4 arguments before object `\NonZeroDimenObject`. It is placed

   - at a radial distance of `2` units (`runits` to be specific) - first argument `{.}`;
   - at a variable angle of `\i` (which ranges from `0` to `345` in steps of `15` degree increments ~ `24` steps in total; according to the definition of `\multido{<type/var>=<start>+<diff>}{<repititions>}{<stuff>}`) - second argument `[.]`;
   - with a fixed rotation of `0` degrees around the object's centre origin - third argument `{.}`; and
   - from the point (x,y) = (`4,4`) - fourth argument `(.,.)`.
2. `\uput{2}[0]{\i}(4,4){\NonZeroDimenObject}`

   Consider the 4 arguments before object `\NonZeroDimenObject`. It is placed

   - at a radial distance of `2` units (`runits` to be specific) - first argument `{.}`;
   - at a fixed angle of `0` - second argument `[.]`;
   - with a variable rotation of `\i` degrees around the object's centre origin (which ranges from `0` to `360` in steps of `5` degree increments ~ 73 steps in total; according to the definition of `\multido{<type/var>=<start>+<diff>}{<repititions>}{<stuff>}`)- third argument `{.}`; and
   - from the point (x,y) = (`4,4`) - fourth argument `(.,.)`.
3. `\uput{<labelsep>}[<refangle>]{<rotation>}(<x,y>){<stuff>}` is a convenience-macro for `\rput` that also does a large amount of heavy-lifting in terms of placing the object at a required reference point. In some (very) special cases, you can use a combination of `\rput` commands to obtain a similar placement to that of `\uput`, as in the following example (a 45 degree angle, say):

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pstricks}% http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/
   \begin{document} 
   \SpecialCoor

   \noindent
   \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
   \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
     \pscircle*(1.5,1.5){1}
     \uput{1.2}[45]{0}(1.5,1.5){$v$}
   \end{pspicture}
   \end{minipage}%
   \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
   \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
     \pscircle*(1.5,1.5){1}
     \rput{0}(1.5,1.5){\rput[bl]{0}(1.2;45){$v$}}
   \end{pspicture}
   \end{minipage}
   \end{document}
   ```

   The output, as expected, is the same.

   Wherein lies the convenience? Well, `\uput` automatically decides the reference point to use when placing the object so that it is guaranteed to be a radial distance `<labelsep>` away from the point of placement. The following example shows this:

   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}% http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone
   \usepackage{multido}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multido
   \begin{document} 

   \SpecialCoor
   \multido{\i=0+15}{24}{%
     \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
       \psline[linecolor=gray,origin={1.5,1.5}](1.2;\i)
       \pscircle(1.5,1.5){1}
       \rput(1.5,1.5){\i}
       \uput{1.2}[\i]{0}(1.5,1.5){$v$}% Example 1
       %\rput{0}(1.5,1.5){\rput{0}(1.2;\i){$v$}}% Example 2
       %\rput{0}(1.5,1.5){\rput[bl]{0}(1.2;\i){$v$}}% Example 3
     \end{pspicture}
   }

   \end{document}
   ```

   The respective output of the three animations are obtained from the above code by commenting in/out the required line for Example 1, 2 or 3.

   Note how `\uput` always maintains a fixed radial distance, while `\rput` suffers from this when using a fixed reference point. Without a fixed reference point, it defaults to the object's centre.

---

The following shows the difference in distances and translations that have to be calculated in order to adequately answer the question:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}% http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone
\usepackage{multido,pst-node}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{multido,pst-node)
\def\Width{3 }
\def\Height{1 }
\def\NonZeroDimenObject{%
    \pspicture(\Width,\Height)\psframe(\Width,\Height)\endpspicture}
\SpecialCoor
\psset{dotscale=0.5}
\begin{document} 

\multido{\i=0+5}{73}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](9,8)
  \pscircle(4,4){2}
  \uput{2}[\i]{0}(4,4){\rnode{MyNode}{\NonZeroDimenObject}\pnode(! \psGetNodeCenter{MyNode} MyNode.x MyNode.y){NZDOcentre}}
  \rput{0}(4,4){\psline[linecolor=blue]{->}(2;\i)}
  \psline[linecolor=red]{->}(4,4)(NZDOcentre)
  \rput(4,4){\i}
\end{pspicture}}
```

The blue line indicates the exact angle and distance the `\uput` command points to, while the red line indicates the centre of `\NonZeroDimenObject`.

Comment: The statement "`\uput` always maintains a fixed radial distance" might be misleading because the referenced points on the object always change.

Comment: @Bugbusters: Yes, `\uput` updates to the appropriate reference point such that the radial distance from the origin (<x,y>) to the object is always `<labelsep>`. To me the phrase is not misleading, but I hope these comments clarify it.

Comment: For the given angle `\alpha` (or the second argument), a line from `(i_x,i_y)` to `(i_x,i_y)+(r;\alpha)`  does not point to the touching point on which the box of non-zero object and the hypothetical circle touch.

Comment: @Werner: The difference between `\uput` and `\rput` is that `\rput`’s reference point is replaced by
`labelsep` and reference angle arguments.

Comment: Please see my update for the first case to know what part confused me. If you  can explain this, the mission will be accomplished for the first case.

Comment: @Bugbusters: For non-zero dimensional objects, the bounding box is rectangular, highlighted by the fact that when I use `\psline[origin={1.5,1.5},linecolor=gray](1.2;45) \pscircle(1.5,1.5){1} \uput{1.2}[45]{0}(1.5,1.5){\fbox{$v$}}` with `\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}`, the line touches the bounding box of the object (see [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QCNys.png)).

Comment: I meant the line does not always point to the touching point between the bounding box of the object and the hypothetical circle.

Comment: @Bugbusters: It doesn't? Show me if you can...

Comment: You can see the first animation in my question. The touching point is not always pointed by the radial line `(4,4)+(2;\i)`. The question is "what is the relationship between the rotation angle and the coordinate of the touching point". This relationship describes algorithm directly. :-)

Comment: @Werner: 45 degrees is a special case.

Comment: Then what is the relationship between the `\alpha` and the center of the non-zero object bounding box? I am sorry. I actually have known what you described above. :-)

Comment: @Werner: your example of `\rput` and `\uput` works only for the special case of alpha=n*45. In all other cases you cannot use `\rput` instead of `\uput`, without doing heavy calculations for the reference point.

Comment: @Herbert: I know this now. I tried to figure out the "heavy calculations" and decided it was too much...

Comment: @Werner: in 3. you say that you can get with `\rput` a similiar behaviour as with `\uput`. You can _not_!

Comment: @Herbert: I read your comment above to imply that it is possible with a lot of work ("...you cannot use `\rput` instead of `\uput`, without doing heavy calculations for the reference point."). And now you mention "You can *not*!". Am I wrong in my first assumption?

Comment: @Werner: "heavy calculations" means creating _new_ macros and/or PostScript functions which is far from beeing useful for users. For a user we have to consider: in general `\rput`/`\uput` cannot be replaced by the another one.

Comment: @Herbert: Okay, I've updated my answer to reflect this, and will remove my comments here momentarily. Thanks for you insights.